# Imputing a missing value with a constant for a categorical data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with many categorical and numerical columns having missing values.
An example for categorical would a column for gender with values 1 & 2 where 1 stands for male & 2 for female with some missing value.

[image: example column]

I want to replace all the NaN in my categorical features with a constant value e.g. "MISSING".
Now, I can map the values to string and use the below pipeline to do my preprocessing.

```
constant_imputer = SimpleImputer(
    strategy="constant", fill_value="Missing", missing_values=np.nan
)
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("imputer_with_constant", constant_imputer),
        ("onehot", onehot_encoder),
    ],
    verbose=True,
)
```

However, I would like to know if there is a solution which would help me directly impute the missing value with whatever constant I want and also would be compatible for adding it as a step in my sklearn pipeline.

Comment: `df = df.replace(np.nan, 'Missing')` OR `df['col'] = df['col'].replace(np.nan, 'Missing')`

Comment: You should use the fillna method to fill missing values, replacing missing data with replace will break in surprising ways. If you're using categorical data you also need to make sure your dtype recognizes the fill value as a valid category.

Comment: Why doesn't your current pipeline with `SimpleImputer` suffice?

Comment: Problem here is the categorical feature is numeric in nature and simple imputer with strategy as constant will only accept an numeric value for fill_value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could query for the cells which contain `nan` and insert you new value with:

```
df[df.isna()] = "Missing"
```

Comment: I want to include the filling of missing values as one of the steps in pipeline and not done separately

Answer (score 0):

Use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.fillna("Missing")
```

Or

```
df.fillna("Missing" , inlace = True)
```